# How to set an HTTP error code in JAX-RS

Tags: java, weblogic, jax-rs, httpresponse

I have a web service using jar-rs. How do I throw a custom http error code to the calling application?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Response](http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/jax-rs/1.0/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) class lets you create a response with a specific HTTP [Status](http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/jax-rs/1.0/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.Status.html). You can also extend [WebApplicationException](https://jsr311.dev.java.net/nonav/releases/1.0/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html).

There are a couple of examples in the [JAX-RS 1.0 features overview docs](http://wikis.sun.com/display/Jersey/Overview+of+JAX-RS+1.0+Features), in the 'Building Responses' and 'WebApplicationException and mapping Exceptions to Responses' sections that will tell you all you need to know to get started.

Comment: Simplest way is probably to just throw a `new WebApplicationException(int statusCode)`

Comment: is there a way to set the HTTP Status code without "throwing an error"? I don't need the message showing up in the console.

Comment: Sure, when building your Response, you'll be using a Response.ResponseBuilder - use the status(Response.Status status) method to set the HTTP status code.